# Module (un)loading procedure in the linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, system-calls

I would like to know how a userspace program like `modprobe` can inject an executable file from userspace to kernel memory?
What kind of syscalls does it issue and what interfaces are provided by the kernel to make that possible? (detailed explanation please).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading a module is done using either one of [`init_module` or `finit_module`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html). The first copies a module from a pointer, the second reads it from a file descriptor. Both support passing additional parameters to the module, and a couple of flags for the kernel.

Unloading a module is done using [`delete_module`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/delete_module.2.html), which takes the name of the module to unload.

If you want to write code which does this, you might want to look into using `libkmod` instead; it’s part of [`kmod`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/kmod/) and available in all distributions.